# Export the Search data to PDF/Print

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to save the searched data into PDF.I used It with help of JS .I am trying to achieve it by any of the two function mentioned in script.both of the function are not working. Kindly help me

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="classification" content="" />
        <title>Geochronology Asset Management System | Add Sample</title>
        <!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE  -->
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $("#pdf").click(function(e){
            $("#tablepdf").tableExport({
                type:'pdf',
                escape:'false'
            });
        });
    });

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

<h2>Export Data to pdf with PHP and MySQL</h2>

<button type="submit" id="pdf" onclick="makepdf()" class="btn btn-info">Export to pdf</button>
<script>
    function makepdf(){

    var printme=document.getElementByid('tablepdf');
    var wme=window.open("","","width:700,height:900");
    wme.document.write(printme.outerHTML);
    wme.document.close();
    wme.focus();
    wme.print();
    wme.close();
    }

    </script>
<table id="tablepdf" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Gender</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Designation</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
  </body>
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION END-->
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES PLACED AT THE BOTTOM TO REDUCE THE LOADING TIME  -->
    <!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- For PDF-->
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jspdf/libs/base64.js"></script><!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->
</html>
```

My button does not seems to work after click.It does not give any reaction.Kindly guide me whether my library file are correct or not

Comment: are you getting any console error's when clicking the button?, check by pressing ctrl+shift+i, and click on console

Comment: @RamondeVries it does not react.No error

Comment: try adding `console.log("test")` in the jquery and javascript as soon as the code starts, so right after the `$(document).ready(function(e){ ` and `function makepdf(){`